# How to change animation easing in Blender 2.8?

Tags: animation

As a blender noob I do animations using auto keyframes. I like to experiment with different animation easing curves. Which I have to choose before adding animations.

[image]

In most cases I d like to experiment and try out a few easing curves, but it is anoying to always reproduce the animations.

[image]
Is there a way to simply change the animation easing in `Dope sheet`editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Easing can be changed within the Dope Sheet in Blender 2.8 by simply selecting the channel and choosing the Interpolation mode in the Key menu.

[image]

Comment: this didnt work for me until i selected it all with A

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that going to the Graph Editor, selecting the right bezier points by pressing `B` and than pressing `T` to set keyframe interpolation, works much better for me.

[image]

[image]

[image]